# IF statement for within this code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Can anyone tell me where to apply an IF statement if a value is '0'

for example:

```
24 May 2015
Premier League
Aston Villa 0 - Burnley 1
6H,6A,
```

output is incorrect as there wasn't a 6H only a 6A - so for home and away I need to apply an IF statement to not post anything should the homeScore = 0

my full code is here

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
from collections import OrderedDict
import time

def parse_page(data):
        #Sleep to avoid excessive requests
        time.sleep(5)

        subsoup = BeautifulSoup(data)
        rs = requests.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/32770767")
        ssubsoup = BeautifulSoup(rs.content)
        matchoverview = subsoup.find('div', attrs={'id':'match-overview'})
        print '--------------'
        date = subsoup.find('div', attrs={'id':'article-sidebar'}).findNext('span').text
        league = subsoup.find('a', attrs={'class':'secondary-nav__link'}).findNext('span').findNext('span').text

        #HomeTeam info printing
        homeTeam = matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('span').findNext('a').text
        homeScore = matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('span').findNext('span').text
        homeGoalScorers = []
        for goals in matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('p').find_all('span'):
            homeGoalScorers.append(goals.text.replace(u'\u2032', "'"))
        homeGoals = homeGoalScorers
        homeGoals2 = ''.join(homeGoals)
        homeGoals3 = re.sub("[^0-9']","",homeGoals2)
        homeGoals4 = homeGoals3.replace("'","',")
        homeGoals5 = homeGoals4.replace("'","H")

        #AwayTeam info printing
        awayTeam = matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'id': 'away-team'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('span').findNext('a').text
        awayScore = matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'id': 'away-team'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('span').findNext('span').text
        awayGoalScorers = []
        for goals in matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'id': 'away-team'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('p').find_all('span'):
            awayGoalScorers.append(goals.text.replace(u'\u2032', "'"))
        awayGoals = awayGoalScorers
        awayGoals2 = ''.join(awayGoals)
        awayGoals3 = re.sub("[^0-9']","",awayGoals2)
        awayGoals4 = awayGoals3.replace("'","',")
        awayGoals5 = awayGoals4.replace("'","A")

        scores = homeGoals5+awayGoals5

        #Printouts
        print date
        print league
        print '{0} {1} - {2} {3}'.format(homeTeam, homeScore, awayTeam, awayScore)
        print scores
        if len(homeTeam) >1:
                with open('score.txt', 'a') as f:
                        writer = csv.writer(f)
                        writer.writerow([league,date,homeTeam,awayTeam,scores])

def all_league_results():
    r = requests.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/results")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    # Save Teams
    for link in soup.find_all("a", attrs={'class': 'report'}):
        fullLink = 'http://www.bbc.com' + link['href']
        time.sleep(5)
        subr = requests.get(fullLink)
        parse_page(subr.text)

def specific_game_results(url):
    subr = requests.get(url)
    parse_page(subr.text)

#get specific games results
specific_game_results('http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/32770767')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly you can simply move print scores inside an if statement that checks if the homeGoals value is greater than 0.

if homeGoals: 
   print scores

if both home and away scores need to be greater than 0 just add another if statement.

if homeGoals: 
  if awayGoals: 
    print scores